# JMeter: How can the props be cleaned between executions?

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan, I'm setting an object inside the props. But then, if I run the test plan twice in a row, the second time that I execute it, the object has the value of the first time. 
Is there any way to "clean" the props after the test has finished? 
I can only find how to clean it after each thread execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update properties in JSR223 Element using `props`

In your case [props.remove("propName")](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/property/CollectionProperty.html#remove-java.lang.String-) will remove specific property.

Also you can override property with function

```
 ${__setProperty("propName", "newValue")}
```