# Clean JMeter Properties of Custom

Tags: jmeter

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596947/jmeter-how-can-the-props-be-cleaned-between-executions?s=1%7C81.6918) Question, but it is not sufficient.

I add timestamp to ProcessId during send Thread like

`props.put(vars.get("processId"), prev.getEndTime());`

and recover/delete them on receive Thread like

```
String processID = vars.get("RefProcessId");
Long senderEndTime = props.get(processID);
```

But sometimes I kill the test then I have dangeling entries in props shown by debug sampler "properties" like this:

```
0000_00705277-a876-4d82-bd94-311e5d0477e7=1523981049548
```

Since i do not have the processID when aborting the test, I tried to remove those dangeling like

```
for(String key: props.stringPropertyNames()) {
    log.info("Key: " + key);
    if(key.startsWith("0000") || key.startsWith("1111")){
        props.remove(key);  
        log.info("Removing: " + key);
    }
}
```

It did not work, and debug sampler doesn't show them.

How can I clean them up?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is adding to test plan [Property Display](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Property_Display) which allow you to update properties values

> Property Display shows the values of System or JMeter properties. Values can be changed by entering new text in the Value column.